# How to detect if a key is pressed multiple times in xna?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm trying to get a texture to toggle on and off when the F1 key is pressed, I can get it to turn on, but it won't turn off again unless I use a separate key to do so.

This works for me:

```
    if(Keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.F1))
     {
       collisionhelp = true;
     }
```

then I do:

```
    if(Keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.F2))
     {
       collisionhelp = false;
     }
```

but what I want is that the second time F1 is pressed, then it sets it to false, but currently that causes it to just not show up at all.

I tried this:

```
    if(Keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.F1))
     {
       collisionhelp = true;

        if(collisionhelp == true && Keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.F1))
         {
           collisionhelp = false;
         }
     }
```

no dice at all, the button doesn't even do anything anymore.

There must be a way to do this in XNA, maybe adding 1 to an integer everytime F1 is pressed and detecting if its even to make if false and if its odd to make it true?

Answer (score 1):

This code will toggle the collisionhelp boolean on and off but it will happen every frame that the F1 key is held down for.

```
if(Keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.F1))
{
    collisionhelp = !collisionhelp;
}
```

So if you are running 60fps and hold the F1 key down for 1 second, it will turn collisionhelp on and off 30 times.

I think what you want is a second boolean to record if the button was pressed in the previous frame and only toggle collision help once per F1 press:

```
if(Keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.F1))
{
    if(!f1AlreadyDown)
    {
        f1AlreadyDown = true;
        collisionhelp = !collisionhelp;
    }
}
else
{
    f1AlreadyDown = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this is what you need:

```
if(Keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.F1))
{
   collisionhelp = !collisionhelp;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying it, and its causing a lot of flickering, what does this do exactly? I'm not really familiar with the ! you put in front, is it the inverse of collisionhelp?

Comment: `!` is called [not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) operator and is inverting boolean value, so `!true == false` and `!false == true`. You should make sure the value changes once per button press to prevent flickering. Try changing the first line into `if(Keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.F1) && Keystate.IsKeyToggled(Keys.F1))` (not sure about that)

Comment: @Nero-One P.S. If previous does not work then I'm misunderstarnding what `IsKeyToggled` function means. In this case you shold do **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259841/button-press-calls-method-multiple-times)**

Comment: The `IsKeyToggled` variable isn't showing up, what I have is `IsKeyUp``IsKeyDown``GetPressedKeys``GetHashCode``Equals``ToString` and `GetType`

Comment: gareththegeek's answer will fix the flickering.